# Whats the correct method of rendering a JPG byte array into an Qt QML ImageObject using an ImageProvider

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, jpeg, qt-creator

Whats the correct method of rendering a JPG byte array into an Qt QML ImageObject using an ImageProvider. This is what I got so far. I just cant seem to render the image properly.

```
  int ret;

   uint32_t size;
    char *data;

   if(this->camera){
        ret = camera->CaptureLiveViewImage(&data, &size);
        if(ret){
            qDebug("Failed to capture live view image from sony camera :(");
            qDebug("pulling data from file");
        }else{
            qDebug("Got image of size %d bytes", size);
        }
    }

   int width = 1024;
    int height = 768;

   if (imageSize){
        *imageSize = QSize(width, height);
    }

   return QPixmap::fromImage(
        QImage(
            (unsigned char *) data,
            requestedSize.width() > 0 ? requestedSize.width() : width,
            requestedSize.height() > 0 ? requestedSize.height() : height,
            QImage::Format_RGB16
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Try https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fromData to load the image, and specify `jpg` or `jpeg` as format parameter

Comment: If you want a real answer, provide us code which compiles, then we could run it and see what you missed.